# Jmeter report generation apdex issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am using apdex report and the current JTL size is >3GB and i see the following issue while generating the report. Could someone suggest a workaround?

```
CMD>jmeter.bat -g .\Result1.jtl -o  .\Report1\
An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Mismatch between expected number of columns:17 and columns in CSV file:30, check your jmeter.save.saveservice.* configuration or check if line 98797899 in 'temp\latencyVsRequest\latencyVsRequest**************-0' is complete
errorlevel=1
```

**Jmeter.log :**
ERROR o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Error parsing property jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date with value: yyyyMMddHHmmss using format: yyyyMMddHHmmss
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:396) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration.loadFromProperties(ReportGeneratorConfiguration.java:677) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.(ReportGenerator.java:154) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:542) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:253) [ApacheJMeter.jar:5.2.1]

ERROR o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Error parsing property jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date with value: yyyyMMddHHmmss using format: yyyyMMddHHmmss
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:396) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration.loadFromProperties(ReportGeneratorConfiguration.java:686) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.(ReportGenerator.java:154) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:542) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:253) [ApacheJMeter.jar:5.2.1]
****TimeStamp***** INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Will use date range start date: yyyyMMddHHmmss, end date: yyyyMMddHHmmss
2020-12-19 10:32:42,607 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.totalTPS.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.

Comment: What is the format of data in the JTL. JMeter supports CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have enough details in order to provide the solution, if you need input from us you need to provide:

1. 1st line of your .jtl file
2. 2nd line of your .jtl file
3. Line 98797899 of your .jtl file
4. Line 98797900 of your .jtl file (if exists)

According to the error you're getting, the columns number doesn't match the header/current JMeter configuration so I can think of the following options:

1. Your test result is really incomplete, if this is the case - either re-run your test and wait for graceful shutdown of all threads or delete the last line of your .jtl file using your favourite text editor. If your test ends prematurely due to error which you don't expect - make sure to check jmeter.log for the execution and follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)
2. If you're merging 2 different .jtl result files make sure that [JMeter Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) is the same for both, if there is an extra column in one of them which you can omit - delete this column and amend the configuration
3. As the last resort you can try generating tables and charts using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which is more "tolerant" to the results file configuration and tries to "guess" the format from the file itself